# Name doesn't exist in current context, but variable has been declared -- Multiple errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Was following along in [this tutorial](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/basics/building-a-graph/) but got an unexpected error:

[image]

Full script file:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Graph : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    Transform pointPrefab;

    [SerializeField, Range(10,100)]
    int resolution = 10;

    Transform[] points;
    points = new Transform[resolution];

    void Awake()
    {
        float step = 2f / resolution;
        var position = Vector3.zero;
        var scale = Vector3.one * step;
        for (int i =0;  i < points.Length; i++)
        {
            Transform point  = Instantiate(pointPrefab);
            position.x = (i + .5f) * step - 1f;
            position.y = position.x * position.x * position.x;
            point.localPosition = position;
            point.localScale = Vector3.one / 5f;
            point.SetParent(transform, false);
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler really doesn't like line 15. First it says "points" doesn't exist in the current context, even though I declared it in the line before. Then it says "invalid token = in class, struct, or member declaration". Then it says "array size cannot be specified in variable declaration".

Comment: You will need to move that line to some initialization method or constructor

Comment: The tutorial isn't clear there. You need to put the line `points = new Transform[resolution];` inside your constructor

Comment: Fixed, thanks all.

Comment: @canton7 you are correct. resolution would have to be static to work that way. Can't edit anymore so the comment has to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to write code directly within the class. That is not allowed.

Normally, you could join the field initializer with the field declaration:

```
Transform[] points = new Transform[resolution];
```

However, an instance field initializer cannot reference other instance fields. In a normal class, you would need to use a constructor:

```
Transform[] points;

public Graph()
{
    points = new Transform[resolution];
}
```

**NB:** As Ruzihm points out in the comments, since this is a `MonoBehaviour`, you should [avoid using a constructor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html). Instead, you should put the initialization in the `Awake` or `Start` method.

```
Transform[] points;

void Start()
{
    points = new Transform[resolution];
}
```

[Fields - C# Programming Guide | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields)

Comment: Yes, moving the trouble line inside the Awake() method (or whatever it would be called) worked.

Comment: It's inappropriate to write constructors for `MonoBehaviour`s. `Awake` or `Start` should be used instead.

Comment: @Ruzihm From what I can see, the main problems are that parameterized constructors aren't supported, the constructor is called from a different thread, and the constructor is called before serialized data has been restored. None of which are a problem here. Am I missing something?

Comment: The Unity docs note under [scripting support](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html): "Note to experienced programmers: you may be surprised that initialization of an object is not done using a constructor function. This is because the construction of objects is handled by the editor and does not take place at the start of gameplay as you might expect. If you attempt to define a constructor for a script component, it will interfere with the normal operation of Unity and can cause major problems with the project."

Comment: Basically, it's an undocumented feature that they can sometimes work for very basic initialization but that isn't guaranteed to work on all platforms and could break without warning.

Comment: In this particular case, there is no guarantee that the serialized field `resolution` will be loaded with the appropriate value when the constructor executes.